# Is "almost" the equivalent word for "quasi"?

Tags: word-usage, english-comparison, translation, word-meaning

I almost quit my job (It implies that I didn't). 
*Ho quasi lasciato il mio lavoro.*

Does it mean exactly the same thing, implying that I still have my job?

Comment: Almost. Sorry, couldn't resist

Comment: Consider also _quasi_ _quasi_ : "quasi quasi sto a casa" -> "I'm tempted to stay home" ( source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/italian-english/quasi )

Answer (score 6):

"Quasi" is fine, but to be more clear (and emphatic) I would have used

> Per poco non lasciavo il lavoro

which conveys clearly both the fact that in the end I opted to keep it, but that I *almost* got there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm Italian and I prefer Vic's version:

> *Ho quasi lasciato il mio lavoro* (perché mi trattano male).

I almost quit my job (because they treat me badly).

Comment: _perché_ , not _perchè_ : please fix that accent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but I'd prefer using *imperfetto* and omitting the possessive

> Quasi lasciavo il lavoro

Comment: Why do you prefer using imperfetto?

Comment: @Vic I find it more colloquial; probably the grammar would prescribe *quasi lasciai il lavoro*.

Comment: consider also regional variations; as a native Italian speaker, I find @egreg's form slightly awkward, while I find yours perfect, despite him being a native Italian speaker from a _nearby_ region.

Comment: The use of the imperfetto confused me, but from what I have studied , "Quasi lasciai il lavoro", could be seen in a book, or heard in Sicily and other southern regions, isn't that right?

Comment: @Vic Probably yes. In the North *passato remoto* is used *really* sparingly; mostly when you want to refer to something that happened a long ago. Although it would be more grammatically correct in most circumstances. By the way: I agree with egreg that *imperfetto* sounds more colloquial and would sound strange only in formal contexts. I think it sounds as if the speaker is somehow "passionate" about the statement (I'd imagine the speaker gesticulating when saying that), while *ho quasi lasciato* sounds a bit detached from the fact.

Answer (score 3):

In your example the two sentences do have the same meaning (compare the definitions: [almost](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/almost), [quasi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quasi/)) but, generally speaking, "almost" and "quasi" are not always equivalent, as "quasi" has one more meaning that "almost" has not.

In fact "quasi" can also mean "as if":

> Come, come se fosse ...: [...] Frequente con un part. pass.: *avanzava veloce, q. portato dal vento*. In funzione di cong. subordinativa (col senso di «come se»), col verbo al congiuntivo: *insisteva, q. avesse ragione lui*;

Source: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quasi/

Answer (score 1):

Still another possibility:

> Stavo quasi per lasciare il mio lavoro

which is not a past continuous :-)